# Как получить названия всех папок из директории реестра

Tags: python, python-3.x, реестр

В моем случаи я хочу узнать названия всех папок из

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\
```

при помощи Python (3.8, если нужно).

Каким образом это можно сделать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53203060/5909792 ?

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
dirs = [ d for d in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isdir(d)]
print(dirs)
```

в твоем случае вместо `.` в `os.listdir` вписываешь путь до директории учитывая особенность записи пути своей операционки